# Counting the maximum number of intersections.

Tags: combinatorics

> Let $n$ be a positive integer. Points $A_1,A_2, \cdots, A_n$ lie on a circle. For $1 \le i <j \le n$, we construct $\overline{A_iA_j}$. Let $S$ denote the set of all such segments. Determine the maximum number of intersection points that can produced by the elements in $S$.

This problem can be solved by using bijection. I already got the answer but I just want to check whether it is right or not.

*My solution.* Define a map that maps the intersection to any four points $(A_i,A_j,A_k,A_l)$ in the circle with $1 \le i<j<k<l \le n$. According to the problem, the number of intersections is maximum, then each intersection gives four points of two segments that create the intersection. Each four points give the intersection of two segments ($\overline{A_iA_k} \cap \overline{ A_j A_l}$). Therefore, this is a one-to-one map. Hence, the maximum number of intersection points is equal to the number of four points $(A,i,A_j,A_k,A_l)$, which is $\binom n4$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have correctly proven that there are always $\leq{n\choose 4}$ points of intersection. I might add the following remarks:

1. It is tacitly assumed that the given points are pairwise different.
2. We make use of the fact that a circle $\gamma$ is convex. Therefore any four points chosen on $\gamma$ form a convex quadrilateral $Q$ whose sides intersect at the given vertices and whose diagonals intersect in the interior of $Q$.
3. Strictly speaking one would have to prove that the maximum of ${n\choose 4}$ points of intersection can actually be realized. (There might be a hidden condition enforcing some of these points to coalesce.)

*Proof of 3:* The statement is obviously true when $n\leq4$. Assume that it is true for $n$ and draw a configuration with ${n\choose4}$ points of intersection. Connect each of the $A_i$ with all of these points by a line. Each of these $n\cdot{n\choose4}$ lines $\ell_k$ intersects $\gamma$ in a second point $P_k$. Now choose $A_{n+1}$ different from all the $A_i$ and all the $P_k$.

Comment: @Michael: Thank you for spotting my blunder. I have edited my answer.